# Where can I buy bus tickets for Indonesia?

Tags: public-transport, tickets, buses, indonesia

I can see there is a website for Indonesian train tickets but I am unable to find a comprehensive website for Indonesia bus services.

I am looking to buy tickets for the following itinerary:

1. Jakarta to Bandung,
2. Bandung to Wonosobo,
3. Wonosobo to Jogjakarta,
4. Jogjakarta to Malang,
5. Malang to Ijen carter

Which is the cheapest option to buy tickets in Indonesia besides buying in advance?

Comment: Is there a reason you want to buy in advance? It should be quite straightforward to just show up at the bus terminal and buy there.

Comment: i need to find a bus connection so that  i make sure buses run with these stops

Comment: you mention buses at the start and trains in the final sentence - are you after buses only?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Would this website be helpful? http://id.easybook.com/?lg=EN#
I have not used this website though.

Another one I found, but it is in indonesian https://ayobis.com/

Probably you already know this one http://www.lonelyplanet.com/indonesia/transport/getting-around/local-transport

Comment: It seems that ayobis only sells tickets that depart from Jakarta. Easybook seems to provide a lot of options, however this is my first time hearing about that website